# iOS application stuck for minutes before becoming active

Tags: ios

I have an application that handles applicationWillResignActive and applicationDidBecomeActive notifications by doing stuff like pausing/unpausing BG music, etc.

I am experiencing a weird bug, in which in every 3-4 times becoming inactive and returning (e.g. locking/unlocking the device), the app seems to be completely stuck for a few *minutes* - meaning, I see the view I'm supposed to see, but I can't touch anything, and music isn't playing.

I debugged it, and it seems that the applicationDidBecomeActive notification is not getting called what so ever.

I looked at the log of my app and literally didn't see anything there for the entire time the app seemed stuck.

The only interesting thing is that in the device's console I could see this line appearing about 10 seconds after I unlock the device and noticing the stuck application.

`Mar 20 11:51:13 unknown MobileStorageMounter[4882] <Notice>: (0x3f4d948c) idle_timer_callback: Exiting after idle timeout`

Not sure if it's related.

Anyone had a similar problem?

Comment: another debugging session revealed that if I disable all calls to the TestFlight SDK the problem is solved.
I will keep this question updated once I figure this out completely with TestFlight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a bug in the TestFlight SDK, upgraded from 0.8.2 to 0.8.3 and problem was solved

Answer (score 1):

It could be that a call to TestFlight is timing out, and prior to the timeout the app locks the main thread, which freezes the interface, until the request is processed or times out. This could happen if the request failed to complete before the system pushed the app into an inactive state, meaning that when it returns to an active state it would still be trying to listen for a response to the request that it will never receive, hence the timeout. The same can occur with Flurry Analytics (at least older versions of the SDK that I have used), and they happen to me as well when calling my own homemade API's and API responses are delayed by a second or two.